# How to add an array to a Mongo entity class?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I want to use List<> to create an array. For example:

```
Class Test{
    public ObjectId Id {get;set;}
    public string name {get;set;}
    public List<Field> fields {get;set;}
}
Class Field{
    public ObjectId Id {get;set;}
    public string name {get;set;}
    public string value {get;set;}
    ......
}
```

This is the code for saving it to the database:

```
var a = new Test();
a.name = "Saw";
var field1 = new Field();
field1.name="BIZMSGID";
a.fields = new List<Field>();
a.fields.Append(field1);
var collection = database.GetCollection<Test>("test");
collection.InsertOne(a);
```

And the result is this.(In Linqpad)
[image]

Why the field1 is not effective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the LINQ method [`Append`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.append?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
a.fields.Append(field1);
```

The remarks section of the documentation for `Append` states:

> This method does not modify the elements of the collection. Instead, it creates a copy of the collection with the new element.

So, in short: you're not modifying `a.fields`, you're creating a LINQ view that has `field1` as the last item.

You should use the List's [add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.add?view=netframework-4.7.2) method:

```
a.fields.Add(field1);
```

Comment: Thanks,Seems I have a wrong understanding for Linq methods :(

Comment: @Sol LINQ methods that return `IGrouping` or `IEnumerable` are just views of the original collection - `.Append()` is one such method. See [this example](https://rextester.com/OVXVX58983).